# Extract matrix in an structure with row and col pair as key in matlab; which one is better map,struct, table

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matrix, struct, cell-array

I'd like to extract each matrix row information in a cell. For example in matrix A, I'd like to store the information in a way that I could be able to use (row,col) pair as a key in the structure. Suppose the my intended data is extracted to structure as following:

```
 Structure A1:
 key1:         (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (4,2) (3,4)  // paranthesis are just not necessary just to show item is extracted from (row,col)
 attribute1:    2      3    4      2     5

 Structure A2:
 key2:         (2,1) (2,2) (1,3) (3,4) 
 attribute2:    1      0    1     5
```

Then, suppose, I'm going to find intersection of structure A1 and A2. The result of intersection would be two item in common (1,2) and (3,4). Then, I use the index to do some calculation on the common item. For example add the value of them. The final value would be

```
(1,2)  (1,3)  (3,4)  //it recognizes (1,2) and(2,1) are the same.
 4       5     10
```

Previously, when I didn't intend to use (row col) pair as a key, I used cell array. But now I wonder if I should map.container structure or not. If I want to use map, then I should change key value to string to be able to store pair as a key. Then the problem of orders remains. that is (2,1) and (1,2) are not equal if I store them as string and I should do some pre-processing to store always the smaller value first. doing sort and then storing for many values is cumbersome.

Is there any faster way to do this? since i'm working with large matrix. What about map using cell array as key or struct? what about table structure? which one would be more efficient?

Another way is to store key values in separate rows, i.e.

```
 Structure A1:
 key row1:      1  1  1  4  3 
 key col1:      1  2  3  2  4
 attribute1:    2  3  4  2  5

 Structure A2:
 key row2:      2  2  1  3 
 key col2:      1  2  3  4
 attribute2:    1  0  1  5
```

Then, if i'm able to search for common entries in both key items simultaneously, that would help and I can use my old cell-array to do the calculation. Is there a way to search in two rows?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you want to do exactly? You have a key, that is a string. Can't you just convert the string to numeric?
t='(1,2)';idx=str2double(regexp(t,'\d*','match'));

M=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];M(idx(1),idx(2))

Comment: You're just trying to sum the matrix with its transpose?

Comment: No, I extract information from multiple sources (matrix) and the information will be stored in something like structure Arow1 and Arow2. I'd like to be able to be able to search for key values. In my example, may be there are multiple (2,1) and (1,2) entries as key values. Then, i'm going to search and find them.

Answer (score 2):

is `sub2ind` can help you?

```
A = reshape(1:1000^2,[1000 1000]);
row = randi(1000);
col = randi(1000);
key = [row,col];
ind = sub2ind(size(A),key,key([2 1]));
sum(A(ind))
```

the third argument (`key([2 1)`) is just replacing the rows with the columns, i.e. getting the transpose matrix's element.

**Update** - multiple `keys` versions:

```
A = reshape(1:1000^2,[1000 1000]);
n = 8;
row = randi(1000,[n 1]);
col = randi(1000,[n 1]);
key = [row,col];
ind = sub2ind(size(A),key,key(:,[2 1]));
sum(A(ind),2)
```

Comment: Interesting answer... Now, is it possible to extend this key value to multiple row and column values? Then, what would be the third argument of sub2ind argument?

Comment: Thank you so much. But sub2ind works for just one matrix? if we have multiple matrix and search for row col and their inverse it doesnt work? (as I mentioned in this question and [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445417/search-parallel-rows-of-a-structures-for-common-items-in-matlab)