# union of two matrices with their common attribute added together in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, union

I have two structure and I'd like to have union of two matrices while the third row is added according to the common first two rows, the result is order-insensitive with respect to the first tow rows and duplicate values are avoided. i.e.

```
% struct1
row1 = [1  1  1  2  4  3];
col1 = [1  2  3  1  2  4];
att1 = [2  3  4  6  2  5];
% struct2
row2 = [2  2  1  3  3];
col2 = [1  2  3  1  4];
att2 = [1  0  1  1  5];
% result
resultRow = [1 1 1 2 2 3]
resultCol = [1 2 3 2 4 4]
resultAtt = [2 10 6 0 2 10]
```

I have the previously asked  [the intersection of two structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445417/search-parallel-rows-of-a-structures-for-common-items-in-matlab) but it seems accumarray works for rows not matrices. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not at all clear how the result vectors are generated from the two sets of input vectors.

Comment: the results are ordered internally in a way that the smaller value between each row and col is chosen for the result row and column and their attribute value are added. `idx1 = sort([row1(:) col1(:)],2);
idx2 = sort([row2(:) col2(:)],2); union(idx1,idx2,'rows') ` gives the the result for the first two rows of results as elaborated in the linked question.

Comment: So what is different from the linked question?

Comment: the linked question is about intersection and this one for union. i'm trying to find the answer for union case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution to [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445417/search-parallel-rows-of-a-structures-for-common-items-in-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1) part of this question, I think we can proceed as follows:

```
% struct1
row1 = [1  1  1  2  4  3];
col1 = [1  2  3  1  2  4];
att1 = [2  3  4  6  2  5];
% struct2
row2 = [2  2  1  3  3];
col2 = [1  2  3  1  4];
att2 = [1  0  1  1  5];
% sort in 2nd dimension to get row-column indexes insensitive for order
idx1 = sort([row1(:) col1(:)],2);
idx2 = sort([row2(:) col2(:)],2);
%find union
[idx,~,bins] = unique([idx1;idx2],'rows','stable');
att = accumarray(bins,[att1,att2]);
ResultUnion= [idx att]';
disp(ResultUnion)
```

and you get

```
ResultUnion =

     1     1     1     2     3     2
     1     2     3     4     4     2
     2    10     6     2    10     0
```